# Транслит на лету

Tags: jquery

Есть 2 инпута, в одно вводится название, в другом должно отображаться транслит введенного на лету.

Comment: Прикольно! А вопрос то где?

Comment: Уже нет вопроса

Comment: очевидно же, что реализация требуется.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[syncTranslit](http://snowcore.net/synctranslit)

> Плагин позволяет синхронизировать два поля на форме, при этом одно поле является источником данных (например, название статьи), а второе (slug) - принимает траслитерированный текст.

Comment: То что нужно. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

```
var translit_array = [];
//...
//...
translit_array[2] = array('в','v');
translit_array[3] = array('г','g');
translit_array[4] = array('д','d');
//...
translit_array[31] = array('ю','yu');
translit_array[32] = array('я','ya');
//Можно использовать ассоциативный массив и for..in, но меня уже разок щелкнули по носу за for...in, вот, теперь извращаюсь
for(var i=0;i<translit_array.length; i++){
  var rep = new RegExp(translit_array[i][0])
  $('textarea#mytextarea').val($('textarea#mytextarea').val().replace(rep,translit_array[i][1]));
}
```

Comment: `translit_array[4] = ['д','d'];` не?

>меня уже разок щелкнули по носу за for...in

`for..in` может негативно сказаться на производительности только если свойство может находится далеко в цепи прототипов, но если объект чист и имеет только собственные(own) свойства, то ничего страшного в использовании `for..in` нету. короче "щёлкнули" вас зря=)

а вот использование такого селектора `'textarea#mytextarea'` это и правда не хорошо, просто id и всё

к тому же в цикле менять значение текстарии...чёт понесло меня на микрооптимизации

Comment: @Spectre - это не микрооптимизации. Если, например, будет написан массивный (но хороший) JavaScript код включая такого рода "ошибки", то, с большой долей вероятности, ни один JS движок не сможет его оптимизировать ( даже если посчитает нужным это сделать )

Так тоже делать плохо:

    arr[0] = ...;
    arr[1] = ...;
    arr[2] = ...;

лучше так:

    [
      ...,
      ...,
      ...
    ];

Лучше как эстетически, так и, в некоторых случаях, с т.з. производительности

Comment: кстати, иногда встречал такой способ работы с массивами:

   // do something with array in loop
   arr[arr.length] = value;

чем вызван такой подход?

Comment: @Spectre - незнанием о существовании метода ***push***

Но это код абсолютно точно !== вызову push, такого рода запись, порой, может очень жестко замедлить вашу логику ( я имею введу **очень** ).

Почему и откуда я это знаю - лучше на спрашивайте, просто поверьте на слово :)

Comment: создатели [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-14) иногда меня удивляют